# How to tag Facebook event by name instead of url address, as we do with pages?

Tags: facebook, events, tags

I'm interested in how to tag a Facebook event post by name? So that the announcement contains only the name of the event that we can click on and that will open that event. As is the practice with F. pages. We use the @pageurl for pages, and for events I can only put a full link. Is there a tagging option, or i have to use an external tool like Bitly?
Thanks in advence for help.
Example: [img_event_tag_by_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1d6V.png)

Tried tagging by event number, name, etc. The only thing I can do is put the entire link.